# Powershell Select-String

Tags: powershell, select-string

I need your help with PowerShell.

I need Select-String with fixed Date (in variable). & Set-Content to result.txt
Example: `$Date = "01.07.2020"`

But also i need select string with date which lower than i written in variable.

My code: `Get-Content -Path log.txt | Select-String "?????" | Set-Content $result.txt`

- In log.txt i have many strings like " Creation date 01.07.2020 " ; " Creation date 01.06.2020 "

Comment: Are the lines in the log file in order? And is that `dd.MM.yyyy` or `MM.dd.yyyy`?

Comment: My script early converted Date from MM.dd.yyyy to dd.MM.yyyy (brfore select data)

I need Select data only. )

Comment: I meant in the source file, `log.txt`

Comment: in source file - dd.MM.yyyy

Comment: And are the lines in the file in order? ie. is lines with `21.08.2020` in them always before lines with `22.08.2020`? Or is it all mixed up? :)

Comment: lines with date are mixed like:

line 1: Creation date 01.07.2020
line 2: Creation date 02.05.2020
line 3: Creation date 28.08.2020
etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

123.txt

```
Creation date 01.07.2020
Creation date 02.05.2020
Creation date 01.06.2020
Creation date 28.08.2020
```

Example script

```
$file = "C:\Users\userprofile\Desktop\test\123.txt"
$regexpattern = "\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}"
$content = Get-Content $file | Where-object { $_ -match $regexpattern}

foreach($line in $content){

    $line.Substring(13,11)

}
```

I used regex to find the lines you are wanting to output. We get the content only if it matches our regex, then for each line we found, I'm using substring to pull the date out. You could also put together a regex for this if you wanted to. Since we know the lines have the same number of characters it's safe to use the substring function.

If you want that output to a file, simply find `$line.Substring(13,11)` and then add this after it `| Out-file "C:\Users\userprofile\desktop\test\output.txt" -append`.